# Linq to XML - Multiple Elements into Single Class

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="Prop1" value="1" />
   <add key="Prop2" value="2" />
</appSettings>
```

Is there a LINQ to XML query to load this section to a single instance of a ConfigProp class?

```
public class ConfigProp
{
   public string Prop1 {get; set;}
   public string Prop2 {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want something like this

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(
    @"<appSettings><add key=""Prop1"" value=""1"" /><add key=""Prop2"" value=""2"" /></appSettings>");
new ConfigProp
{
    Prop1=xml
        .Elements("add")
        .Single(element=>element.Attribute("key").Value == "Prop1")
        .Attribute("value")
        .Value,
    Prop2 = xml
        .Elements("add")
        .Single(element => element.Attribute("key").Value == "Prop2")
        .Attribute("value")
        .Value
};
```

Note that if your xml does not contain the Prop1 and Prop2 keys this with throw an exception.

Comment: As is - this doesn't work. You need `xml.Descendants("add")` or  `xml.Element("appSettings").Elements("add")` instead of `xml.Elements("add")` - then it'll work...

Comment: @marc_s that's true if you assume `xml` is an `XDocument` for the given XML and since I didn't really specify what it is that's not an invalid assumption.  I've updated to make my intentions clear.

Answer (score 4):

Why you dont't use this?

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Prop1"];
```